# Should this question edit be rolled back?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

This was a simple question but the OP is being extremely stubborn for some reason. Anyways, he edited the question to basically remove all the details from it. As it stands now, it's not really a question anymore.

[What HTML what tag should I use when I just don't want a specific one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482522/what-html-what-tag-should-i-use-when-i-just-dont-want-a-specific-one)

Not that the previous context was any better, basically causing a semantic battle over why he should use the `<hr />` element. Moderators, I wouldn't mind if you went on a comment-deleting spree. This question ended up being way more effort than it should've been; I'm tempted just to delete my answer (but I know I shouldn't).

Anyways, I was thinking of rolling the edit back, but I figured he'd probably go off on me in the comments, so I thought I'd ask. Something should be done about this question, I have no idea what. He doesn't seem to believe that my answer actually answers his original question.

Comment: Unfortunately the OP has shot himself in the foot and I doubt the post will recover from the downvotes it attracted. I could roll back but I think it's a lost cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would roll it back if the OP's edit caused it to lose context, which is what has happened here. The OP would have been better off if he had rephrased the question, rather than removing just about everything.

Occasionally an edit battle will ensue, in that case just flag it for moderator attention and let them deal with it. As AntiSanta mentioned, it is counter-productive for the OP to mess with the post too much (no matter how stupid they think we are) due to the number of down votes and close votes it will receive.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the question is any good in the edited form, but the OP has indicated that the original form did not express his actual intent.

I've left a comment advising further revision, and will check back later to see if that has been done. If not I'll vote to close.