# Should we pick an answer that answered the question, or answered the problem?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which answer do I accept if I have multiple correct answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/which-answer-do-i-accept-if-i-have-multiple-correct-answers)
>   [What answer to accept?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28276/what-answer-to-accept)

I answered this question: [Self invoking function that can be called as well](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9932845/561731) Which answered the OPs issue with how they were going about their issue.

But the [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932845/self-invoking-function-that-can-be-called-as-well/9932882#comment12680637_9932882) stated that they are picking the other answer due to it answering the question at hand.

How should someone respond to this type of thing?

Seems a bit Help Vampirey, but I am not sure.

Comment: Sounds like a [problem I had](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115809/141525). Stubborn people...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> How should someone respond to this type of thing?

There is no need for you to respond to this in any way.

It has been covered over and over on meta (even since *I've* been here, and you've been around much longer than I have) that the asker of a question can choose any answer they like, for whatever reason they like.  It's totally up to them.

You got some upvotes, and obviously helped the OP some.  Time to move along.

Comment: Haha, yes I know that. Just it seems like people could get the wrong impression when they see an answer that does not look entirely correct, and did **not** solve the OPs issue as an accepted answer.

Comment: @amanaP Upvotes and downvotes are the indicators for whether the *community at large* thinks an answer is correct / helpful.  The check mark is *just* an indication that the answer was helpful to the OP.

Comment: True true. It just irritates me...

Comment: @amanaP I can understand the irritation.  I *don't* think that's a great reason to immediately post on meta, but that's just me.  You posted this question less than 5 minutes after that exchange happened.